# Apache ECharts Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"pictorialBar"'?

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6isfrx?file=src%2Fechart.component.ts) works.

However the options use `any` and I'm trying to convert them over to the `EChartOption` type.

And this is what I have so far and the demo compiles fine with this (With `type: 'bar'` commented out).

```
  testOptions: EChartsOption = Object.assign(
    {},
    {
      grid: {
        left: '6%',
        right: '6%',
        bottom: '4%',
        top: '3%',
        containLabel: true,
      },
      xAxis: {
        axisLabel: {
          color: 'gray',
          fontSize: '16',
        },
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'blue',
            width: 4,
          },
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false,
        },
        splitLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'gray',
            width: 1,
          },
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        data: this.labels,
        axisLabel: {
          color: 'pink',
          fontSize: 22,
        },
        axisLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'orange',
            width: 4,
          },
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          // For shadow
          //type: 'bar',
          data: this.data.map((v) => this.maxValue),
          cursor: 'default',
          itemStyle: {
            normal: {
              color: 'gray',
            },
            opacity: 1,
          },
          barWidth: '40%',
          barGap: '-100%',
          barCategoryGap: '30%',
          animation: false,
          z: 1,
        },
      ],
    }
  );
```

If `type: 'bar'` is commented in, the demo produces the compilation error.

```
Error in src/echart.component.ts (23:3)
Type '{ grid: { left: string; right: string; bottom: string; top: string; containLabel: boolean; }; xAxis: { axisLabel: { color: string; fontSize: string; }; axisLine: { lineStyle: { color: string; width: number; }; }; axisTick: { ...; }; splitLine: { ...; }; }; yAxis: { ...; }; series: { ...; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'EChartsOption'.
Types of property 'series' are incompatible.
Type '{ type: string; data: number[]; cursor: string; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; opacity: number; }; barWidth: string; barGap: string; barCategoryGap: string; animation: boolean; z: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOption$1 | SeriesOption$1[] | undefined'.
Type '{ type: string; data: number[]; cursor: string; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; opacity: number; }; barWidth: string; barGap: string; barCategoryGap: string; animation: boolean; z: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'BarSeriesOption$1 | LineSeriesOption$1 | ScatterSeriesOption$1 | PieSeriesOption$1 | ... 18 more ... | SeriesOption$1[]'.
Type '{ type: string; data: number[]; cursor: string; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; opacity: number; }; barWidth: string; barGap: string; barCategoryGap: string; animation: boolean; z: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOption$1[]'.
Type '{ type: string; data: number[]; cursor: string; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; opacity: number; }; barWidth: string; barGap: string; barCategoryGap: string; animation: boolean; z: number; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOption$1'.
Type '{ type: string; data: number[]; cursor: string; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; opacity: number; }; barWidth: string; barGap: string; barCategoryGap: string; animation: boolean; z: number; }' is not assignable to type 'PictorialBarSeriesOption$1'.
Type '{ type: string; data: number[]; cursor: string; itemStyle: { normal: { color: string; }; opacity: number; }; barWidth: string; barGap: string; barCategoryGap: string; animation: boolean; z: number; }' is not assignable to type 'PictorialBarSeriesOption'.
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"pictorialBar"'.
```

So trying to figure this out, because `bar` should work fine for the type option [according to the Apache ECharts documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar).

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK figured it out ... It's because `Object.assign` is used to create the options instance.

If we just assign the options with an object instance it works fine.

This is a demo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-25c1rp?file=src%2Fechart.component.ts